# java program: Adding Integers from users string input

Tags: java, methods, integer

For this program I am taking input as a string with the following format: A name, followed by integers separted by spaces. There can be one or more integers in the series. Its output ends up being the name of the series and its sum. Here is an example of the what the output should be:

```
Series? seriesname 1 3 5 7 11
sum(seriesname) = 27
```

I am having problems with my code, It keeps having issues with this line (the exception):

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(series.substring(start, space));
```

I have moved quite a bit around but this is what I have right now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NamePlusAddingInts {
    public static String series;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Series? ");

        series = scan.nextLine();
        String name = series.substring(0, series.indexOf(' '));

        System.out.print("Sum(" + name + ") = " + number);
    }
    public static int adding() {
        int space = series.indexOf(' ');

        while (space != -1) {
            int start = space + 1;
            int number = Integer.parseInt(series.substring(start, space));

            number = number + number;
            space++;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am having problems with my code, It keeps having issues with the:` - what are the issues?

Comment: Why your code not working? what is the error/exception?

Comment: The parameters to `substring` are the beginning character, and the ending character (plus 1).  You have things set up so that the beginning is always *after* the ending character.  That cannot work.

Comment: I think what you want with your `substring` is to have the program get the substring up to the *next* space.  This seems right, but in order to do that, you have to _tell_ the program to find the next space.  You will probably want to use a different version of `indexOf`.  This is documented at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-).

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it. You have clear separators between things that interest you, you could just split the string at spaces, take the first element as name and make the code much clearer, consider this:

```
    String numbers = "name 5 20 26 4 2 13";
    String[] splitNumbers = numbers.split(" ");

    int sum =0;
    String name = splitNumbers[0]

    for(int i = 1; i < splitNumbers.length ; i++){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(splitNumbers[i]);
    }
```

Now just change the hard-coded numbers value to user input and its done. You can surround it in try-catch to check for format exceptions if you're afraid of user inputting something other than numbers.

Comment: sum += splitNumbers[i]; this will only give a concatenated string. You should parse your numbers to int and then do the sum

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation of the adding() method will be to break the long string into a string array. You can call the `String` method, `split(" ")` to convert the string into string array.

```
public static int adding(String input) {
    int sum = 0;
    String[] array = input.split(" ");

    //starts from 1 because array[0] is the name of the series
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sum += array[i]; this will only give a concatenated string. You should parse your numbers to int and then do the sum

Comment: oops accidentally left that out haha. Thanks btw!